# how to differentiate text boxes

Tags: php, javascript, html

sorry for weird question...

so i want to alert (testing for now) values of text boxes using javascipt and php and right now, i have loops creating various text boxes with the same name. when i try to alert a text box with a name, it chooses only the first one... i'm not sure how to deal whit this. is there a way to do this with forms or div? heres some code...

```
function insertComment(comment){
     alert(comment);
}

//say... i have a for loop that makes 5 of these 
echo "<textarea rows='3' cols='20' name='txt_comment' id = 'txt_comment'>Enter comment here...</textarea>" . "</br>";
echo "<button onClick='insertComment(txt_comment.value)'>Submit Comment</button>";
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give each text box a same class say "text-boxes" and then use jquery method each

```
$("input.text-boxes").each(...);
```

or try giving diff id to each textbox if using a loop like

```
loop for $i
"text-comment" . $i
```

and in js function loop with the same thing

```
for i = 1 to 5
  ..document.getElementById("text-comment" + i).value..
```

Comment: hi, i'm very interested in this .each but i'm not very familiar with jquery, does this code go into the javascript or when defining the text boxes? will this go in my php code?

Comment: jquery is javascript .sure you can use jquery with php , but it will be functional only on browser side . you can use like create text boxes with php and then use or manipulate them with jquery .. here's the link for [jquery api](http://www.jqapi.com) . its pretty easy . and for [each function](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=each)

Answer (score 1):

not sure but should have to work with `.each()` with jquery, this will help you to creating loop over the selected element...

Answer (score 0):

You could give different `id`s to the text boxes using the for loop index and retrieve the require field by `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp):

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the id
>   attribute value must be unique within the HTML document).

So you shouldn't have 5 textareas with same id. One solution is to give different ids to textareas.
Other solution is using [`getElementsByTagName('textarea')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) and then loop inside the node list.
You can also use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) if you assign a class to your textareas.